# Concatenate MultiIndex Dataframes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Multindex dataframes (**date** and **ticker** are indexes)

**df_usdtbtc**:

```
                         close
date          ticker                                                     
2017-12-31    USDT_BTC   13769
2018-01-01    USDT_BTC   13351
```

and **df_ethbtc**:

```
                         close
date          ticker                                                     
2017-12-31    USDT_ETH   736
2018-01-01    USDT_ETH   754
```

Is there any way to merge, concat or join these 2 dataframes to get as a result this dataframe :

```
                         close
date          ticker                                                     
2017-12-31    USDT_BTC   13769
              USDT_ETH   736
2018-01-01    USDT_BTC   13351
              USDT_ETH   754
```

To help set up the dataframes :

```
df_usdtbtc = {'dates':  [dtm(2018, 1, 1),dtm(2018, 1, 2)], 'ticker': ['USDT_BTC', 'USDT_BTC'],'close':[13769,13351]}
df_usdteth = {'dates':  [dtm(2018, 1, 1),dtm(2018, 1, 2)], 'ticker': ['USDT_ETH', 'USDT_ETH'],'close':[736,754]}
df_usdtbtc = pd.DataFrame(data=df_usdtbtc)
df_usdtbtc=df_usdtbtc.set_index(['dates','ticker'])
df_usdteth = pd.DataFrame(data=df_usdteth)
df_usdteth=df_usdteth.set_index(['dates','ticker'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) or [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df_usdtbtc, df_ethbtc]).sort_index()
```

Or:

```
df = df_usdtbtc.append(df_ethbtc).sort_index()
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df_usdtbtc, df_ethbtc]).sort_index()
print (df)
                     close
date       ticker         
2017-12-31 USDT_BTC  13769
           USDT_ETH    736
2018-01-01 USDT_BTC  13351
           USDT_ETH    754
```